# Get all classes which extend class inferring certain generics

Tags: java, generics

I am looking for some way to get all classes that extend a certain class and infer certain generics. 
I know that using `Reflections` i can get all classes that extend a class

```
final Reflections reflections = new Reflections("path.to.package");
Set<Class<? extends ClassBase>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(ClassBase.class);
```

but i'm not sure how to get only those using certain generics. Here's an example of what i want to achieve

Let's assume i have `ClassBase<T>`

```
public class ClassBase<T> {}
```

Then i have `ClassA ClassB ClassC`, all of them extending `ClassBase`

```
public class ClassA extends ClassBase<Long> {}

public class ClassB extends ClassBase<Long> {}

public class ClassC extends ClassBase<Integer> {}
```

How do i get only `ClassA` and `ClassB`? I'm even ok with getting all the classes that extend `ClassBase` and then filter out those i don't need, as long as i end up with a set containing only those classes which extend `ClassBase` and infer `<Long>` as generic type.
Or better, i actually want a `Set<Class<ClassBase<Long>>>` not just a `Set<Class<ClassBase>>` which contains only those inferring `Long` as generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the inferred generic type using by using the function [`getGenericSuperclass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass()) and then [`getActualTypeArguments`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments()) Here's an example:

```
// Given that all classes in this set are actually subclasses of ClassBase
Set<Class<? extends ClassBase>> classes = Set.of(ClassA.class, ClassB.class, ClassC.class);
System.out.println(classes); // [class test.ClassB, class test.ClassA, class test.ClassC]

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Set<Class<? extends ClassBase<Long>>> result = classes.stream()
    .filter(cls -> {
        // Get superclass, which is ClassBase, so assume it's also parameterized
        ParameterizedType superClass = (ParameterizedType) cls.getGenericSuperclass();
        Type inferred = superClass.getActualTypeArguments()[0]; // get first type argument
        return inferred == Long.class; // check if it's 'Long'
    })
    // Can now say they all extend ClassBase<Long>
    .map(cls -> (Class<? extends ClassBase<Long>>) cls)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

System.out.println(result); // [class test.ClassA, class test.ClassB]
```

You get a `Set<Class<? extends ClassBase<Long>>>` which holds classes that extend `ClassBase<Long>`. A `Set<Class<ClassBase<Long>>>`, that you ask for, should only technically hold the class `ClassBase` itself, while you're actually interested in the sub classes, so you get `Class<? extends ClassBase<Long>>`.

Answer (score 0):

For people using spring and have those classes managed by the container (they are annotated with some spring annotation like `@Service`, `@Component`), you can get all the classes with the following approach:

```
@Inject Set <ClassBase <Long>> extensionsWithLongType;
```